# C++ SDL Resolution

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to make a game using the SDL library, and I'm wondering on what resolution I should make the game on. Sadly I dont know how windows handles different resolutions so I have no clue on what resolution I should make the game on.  So what resolution should I use?

I read somewhere in a similar post on stackoverflow that it changes the resolution on the fly.  Can anyone confirm this? If anyone has any articles that explain this matter please share, I couldn't find any on google.

Comment: SDL lets you query the available resolutions, doesn't it?

Comment: Im not sure what you ment but I think I finally found the answer. 

"SDL_FULLSCREEN SDL will attempt to use a fullscreen mode. If a hardware resolution change is not possible (for whatever reason), the next higher resolution will be used and the display window centered on a black background."

I'm guessing I can just go with a high resolution and it will shrink for PC's that cant handle it?

Comment: Sorry, I may have been confusing SDL and Allegro. The latter definitely lets you enumerate available modes, but now I'm not sure if SDL also has such a feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`SDL_ListModes`](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_ListModes) to enumerate available resolutions and pick one from those. The `flags` parameter should be something like `SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_FULLSCREEN`.

Answer (score 0):

SDL Allows you to reset the video mode the same way you set it up in the first place, through a call to SDL_SetVideoMode, the resolution will reset to the new video mode.

However, if you ever decide to use SDL to hook OpenGL into, when you call the SDL_SetVideoMode function you will lose your OpenGL context, and all the textures and states along with it, so be sure to reload all of them on screen resolution change.

Also if you want some good SDL articles, check out this link
[Lazyfoo SDL tutorials](http://www.lazyfoo.net)